# Error while importing 'speech' from 'google.cloud'?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api

error (unknown location) while importing speech from googleCloud??

```
import io
import os
import google

# Imports the Google Cloud client library
from google.cloud import speech
from google.cloud.speech import enums
from google.cloud.speech import types
```

.................

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/FILES/4 Year/Gp/specch-Rec-Demo/google-cloud.py", line 11, in <module>
  from google.cloud import speech
  ImportError: cannot import name 'speech' from 'google.cloud' (unknown location)
```

Comment: Do you have `google-cloud-speech` library installed? Try `pip install google-cloud-speech` or `pip3` if you are using Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a [virtual environment](https://cloud.google.com/python/setup#installing_and_using_virtualenv) to use the speech API and islote dependencies.

After setting the environment you should [install](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python) the dependency by using this command:

```
pip install --upgrade google-cloud-speech
```

In order to start using this library, you should create a service account and set the environment variable **GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS** to the file path of the JSON file that contains your service account key, I suggest to follow the next [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/quickstart-client-libraries) to learn how to use Google Speech to Text with Python